# agregar objetos a un array

Tags: javascript

realizar un codigo con array de numeros donde englobe a dos numeros dentro del array.
ej:
[4,6,1,12,9,15,21,0]  debe retornar [[4,6],[1,12],[9,15],[21,0]]

```js
let array=[4,6,1,12,9,15,21,0];  //[[4,6],[1,12],[9,15],[21,0]]
for (let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    let newArray=array.map(x=>[x,x])
console.log(newArray[i]);
}
```

no se como hacer para que avance al siguiente numero.

Comment: porque no recorres el array no de a uno sino de dos en dos , y para cada elemento lo juntas  con el siguiente (i + 1)?

Answer (score 1):

`map` sirve para generar un nuevo arreglo mediante modificaciones a los elementos individuales del arreglo original.

También noto que lo mezclaste con un for, repitiendo el mismo código innecesariamente.

Esto es equivalente y más simple:

```js
let array = [4,6,1,12,9,15,21,0];
let newArray = array.map(x => [x, x])

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(newArray[i])
}
```

---

Como sugiere @Pipe, usa algún ciclo para esa tarea:

```js
let array = [4,6,1,12,9,15,21,0]
let newArray = []

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    newArray.push([ array[i], array[i + 1] ])
}

console.log(newArray)
```

O si prefieres usar `forEach`:

```js
let array = [4,6,1,12,9,15,21,0]
let newArray = []

array.forEach((number, index) => {
    let i = Math.floor(index / 2)
    let j = index % 2

    if (j == 0)
        newArray[i] = []

    newArray[i][j] = number
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Encuentro que es más elegante ejecutar cualquier mapeo, filtro o transformación en general mediante métodos nativos del array antes que declarar una variable libre fuera del bucle.

Mi solución sería ocupar `Array.prototype.reduce` (que en cada iteración recibe un valor acumulado, el item actual, y el índice de éste).
Si el índice es par, toca crear una nueva tupla cuyo primer elemento es el ítem actual.
Si el índice es impar, toca completar la tupla que quedó incompleta en el paso anterior. Toda la operación queda encapsulada:

```js
let arr = [4, 6, 1, 12, 9, 15, 21, 0];

const pares = arr.reduce((accum, value, index) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    accum.unshift([value])
  } else {
    accum[0].push(value)
  }
  return accum;
}, []).reverse()

console.log(pares);
```

Es más eficiente? No, para nada. Es como 33% más lento que hacerlo con un ciclo `for`. Pero a veces un snippet que se explica solo y no expone variables al exterior es más robusto.

Answer (score 0):

Tomando esta respuesta [Convert a 1D array to 2D array [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22464838/13636459), puedes usar un `while` e ir partiendo el `array` de dos en dos:

```js
let array=[4,6,1,12,9,15,21,0];  //[[4,6],[1,12],[9,15],[21,0]]
   
const newArr = [];
while(array.length) newArr.push(array.splice(0,2));
    
console.log(newArr);
```

`array.splice(0,2)` devuelve 2 elementos desde el índice 0 y simultáneamente los "elimina" de la lista original.

Comment: Solo una observación: Como dijo el compañero, este método además de crear un `newArr` con lo valores que se necesitan, también modifica el valor original de `array`.